# Counting terms in a product of sum

Tags: combinatorics

I wonder how to count the number $N_{t,k}$ of terms in the following product (when we expand it as a sum of monomials) where all variables is of degree at least two:
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^t a_i\right)^k$$

For example, when $t=2$, $k=5$, the answer would be 22: $a_1^5, a_2^5$, ten terms of various permutations of $a_1^2 a_2^3$, and ten other terms equivalent to $a_1^3 a_2^2$.

I know I can write the number of terms as a huge sum using inclusion-exclusion, but that formula is hard to evaluate. If it is hard to calculate the exact number, any ideas on bounding this number will be appreciated too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all the terms in $a_1^3a_2^2$ should combine into one.  You should just have one term for each power of $a_1$ as $a_2$ then comes with five minus that power, so six terms.  You are missing $a_1^4a_2$ and $a_1a_2^4$.  If you don't allow the $a$s to commute, it is just $2^5=32$ terms in your example and $t^k$ in general.

Added: You want to expand the product without allowing commutivity between the $a_i$.  We want the number of terms where there is not $a_i$ to the power $1$, but power $0$ or higher powers are allowed.  If we ignore the restriction of avoiding first powers there are $t^k$ terms, so that is an upper bound.

Let us define $A(t,k)$ as the number of terms in your sum that do not have one variable only once.  This is the same as the number of strings of length $k$ from an alphabet of size $t$ that do not have one letter exactly once.  A string of $k$ terms that has every letter at least twice can be a string of $k-1$ terms that we add one more letter that matches a previous one, or it can be a string of $k-2$ terms that we put two of a new letter in, one of which goes at the end.  Let $B(t,k)$ be the number of strings of length $k$ on $t$ letters where every letter is represented at least twice.  Then $$B(t,k)=tB(t,k-1)+(k-1)B(t-1,k-2)$$
because you can start with a string of $t-1$ letters from an alphabet of $k$ and add one or you can start with a string of $t-2$ letters from $k-1$ and add one somewhere and another at then end.  Then $$A(t,k)=\sum_{t'=1}^t{t \choose t'}B(t',k)$$ because we just sum over the number of letters that are there weighted by the number of ways to choose the letters represented from our alphabet.

Comment: Yes, I probably didn't formulate the question clearly enough: I'm precisely skipping $a_1^1a_2^4$ terms because I want only terms where all variables are of degree at least two.

Comment: But the $a_2^0$ doesn't eliminate the $a_1^5$ term?  That seems strange, but we can deal with it.  It also seems strange not to combine all the terms with various orders of $a_1^3a_2^2$ but again we can deal with it.  I'll think on it.

Comment: I think it’s also the case that $A(t,k)=\sum_{\sum a_j=k\land\forall j, a_j\neq1}{k\choose{a_1, a_2,\dots,a_t}}$? Whether that’s easier to get a closed form for, I’m not sure.